# Add values to javascript object array

Tags: javascript

I want to create an javascript object with key value pairs looks like:

```
var data = {
    'key': ["p1","p2","p3"], 
    'product': ["xxx1","xxx2","xxx3"]
};
```

i have tried

```
data.key="some value"; //  is not working
```

how can append new keys and product to this list? I was an ios developer and iam a newbie in JS, Thanks.

Comment: your code seems to be valid. I have put up fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/mv5WP/2/

Answer (score 3):

They are arrays. You can [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to them.

```
data.key.push('new_value');
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have class:

```
function data() {
    this.key = new Array();
    this.product = new Array();
}
```

access that class:

```
var obj = new data();
obj.key.push("p1");
obj.key.push("p2");
obj.key.push("p3");
```

i think this will be help you.

Answer (score 0):

If they really are key value pairs, why not store them as such??

```
var data = { "p1" : "xxx1", "p2" : "xxx2", "p3" : "xxx3" };
```

Then you can just go

```
data[ "p4"] = "xxx4";
```

If your actual object contains more fields then you would have

```
var data = { 
    "p1" : { product: "xxx1" },
    "p2" : { product: "xxx2" }, 
    "p3" : { product: "xxx3" }
};
```

Comment: how can i push a new product and key?

Comment: This is not a stack - to add a new product/key you would simply do data[newKey] = { "product": newProduct };

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var datatest = new Object(); // var datatest = {};
>
>           datatest.key = [] ;
>           datatest.key.push('p1') ;
>           datatest.key.push('p2') ;
>           datatest.key.push('p3') ;
>           datatest.product = [] ;
>           datatest.product.push('xxx1') ;
>           datatest.product.push('xxx2') ;
>           datatest.product.push('xxx3') ;
> ```

I have tried doing this on my side by creating key and products as an array and pushing with the required values.